# Оплата на сайте laravel

Tags: laravel

мне нужна консультация по поводу подключение платежной системы на сайт laravel, т.е. я знаю про Cachier, но как привязать сами транзакции к конкретному расчетному счёту сбербанка?

Comment: данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что его следует адресовать в техподдержку (или к документации) используемой платёжной системы